# How to wait and then click on the first link in html table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting to play with selenium and I am looking for some help. On my webpage that I'm attempting to test I have a search button and when the page loads I have a html table that appears below it with results.

[image]

The html of the search results table is as follows...

```
<table id="search-results-table" style="width: 1561px;">
    <thead>
    <tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
        <th><div>Item Description</div></th>
        <th><div>Size</div></th>
        <th><div>Colour</div></th>
        <th><div>Supply Style</div></th>
        <th><div>Item #</div></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="left  sorting_1 ">EASY STEPS TAC LILYPAD PUMP:GREEN:10</td>
        <td class=" center">10</td>
        <td class=" center">GREEN</td>
        <td class=" center">TAC</td>
        <td class=" center"><a href="javascript:setItemNumber(217592380);">217592380</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using selenium IDE i was able to work out how to create a junit test that does a search like the one in the screen shot but I am struggling to work out how I can modify the unit test to properly wait for the search to finish and then once the results are returned on the page, to click on the first item in the first row of the search results table.

Appreciate if someone could help. Below is the code that I have tried to so far but it is not returning any td's for my table. Sorry I am a real beginner.

```
public class MySearch {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();    
  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    File file = new File("C:/selenium/IEDriverServer.exe");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();  

    baseUrl = "http://myBaseUrl";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
  @Test
  public void testSearch() throws Exception {    
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/wps/portal/mySearchUrl");      
    driver.findElement(By.id("keywords")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("keywords")).sendKeys("BLACK SHOES");
    driver.findElement(By.id("searchButton")).click();
    navigateToDetail();        
  }
  public void navigateToDetail() throws Exception {
        //find tbody
        WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("search-results-table"));

        //get all rows
        List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        //iterate through the rows
        for (WebElement row : allRows) {
                //get the rowCells in each row
                List<WebElement> rowCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

                int indexofColumnwhichhasProjectname = 4;

                //get the column which contains the item no and get text
                String itemNo = rowCells.get(indexofColumnwhichhasProjectname).getText();

                System.out.println(itemNo);
        }
    }
```

When debugging through the output it the part where I try and get the td's that returns nothing so of course when I try and get index 4 it returns an arryIndexOutOfBounds.

```
List<WebElement> rowCells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Alecxce for help with this. In the end I've found an xpath expression that did the trick.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='search-results-table']/tbody/tr[‌​1]/td[5]/a")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly wait for search results to be visible:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("search-results-table")));
```

Comment: thanks Alecxe. I tried to put that in the code before calling navigateToDetail() but still no good. I'm not sure if that's the problem though because i am getting data back for my tr's but not td's.

Comment: @Richie thanks, could you post the HTML of the page before clicking "Search"?

Comment: Alecxe I found another way to do what I was trying to do....driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='search-results-table']/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]/a")).click();

Comment: @Richie thanks for sharing. I think you can post your solution as an answer and accept so that we can resolve the topic.